# PHP Return each value of an array individually

Tags: php, html

Basically I am currently creating a CMS (A bit like Wordpress) as a project and for a website.

Currently I am working on my "tab" system, which is how it sounds. What I need it to do is print all the different "tabs" (Which are hyperlinks with text). But currently my function, which I will get too in a minute, only prints out the last value in my SQL database.

The function is as follows:

```
function getTabs($id, $text, $link, $test)
{
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        text,
        link
        FROM cms_tabs");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($text, $link);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('text' => $text, 'link' => $link);
        $rtn = ('<a href='.$link.'>'.$text.'</a>');
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return ($rtn);
}
```

Now I know this is going to be a really simple fix... Something like `$row(i)`, however I have been staring at my code for too long and I can't think of a solution.

Comment: `$rtn .= (...)`, the point before the equal sign means concatenations of strings, right now on each iteration you are simply overriding that value, also note that you are not using the query results.

Comment: Thank you. So very much. If I could hug you right now, I would.

Comment: Gatus.... :3 @Laurie Walpole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$rtn = ('<a href='.$link.'>'.$text.'</a>');
```

to

```
$rtn .= ('<a href='.$link.'>'.$text.'</a>');
```

whole code is:

```
    function getTabs($id, $text, $link, $test)
{
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        text,
        link
        FROM cms_tabs");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($text, $link);
    rtn = '';
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('text' => $text, 'link' => $link);
        $rtn .= ('<a href='.$link.'>'.$text.'</a>');
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return ($rtn);
}
```

Comment: because the answer was already given in the comment and there is no point in copying the answer..

Comment: I didn't -1, it works. Thanks, the guy above had already solved it though.